# Blank Page HTML

Tags: html

I am a beginner trying to learn HTML. I have just set up my Web Development environment (I am using Visual Studio Code for reference). Although I have written text, on my HTML file, when I copy the path and paste it to my browser, it opens up to an empty page.

The HTML code is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>ASL Investment Club</h1>
    </body>
</html>


<!-- /Users/robertg21/Visual Studio Code Projects/hello_html/index.html -->
```

I am unsure of whether this is an error with the file itself, or the path (shown above) I am using (or maybe even the browser itself). I would be very grateful if anyone had any solutions on how to fix this.

EDIT: My bad, the file wasn't saved in advanced and therefore didn't render any text. I am sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: Add the path you're using in the browser. Try to open directly the file instead of paste the path.

Comment: Did you try using the Open command from the browser, so you can navigate to your file?

Comment: Your HTML looks fine and renders fine on my end. How exactly are you trying to open it in your browser, and using what browser?

Comment: If you go to View Source in your browser do you see your HTML code? If not, maybe you are pasting the wrong path.

Comment: Worked perfectly fine for me.  Saved the file to my desktop as `index.html` and opened it perfectly in Chrome.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://codepen.io/dorward/pen/ZNNbvL

Comment: I have copied the path onto my chrome browser and nothing renders

Comment: Also, are you sure the code you posted here is exactly the same as your code? Maybe you are missing a `</title>` or `</head>` or forgot to close one of your angle brackets `>`. You could also use an online HTML validator to try validating your code.

Comment: what is the name and file type of your html file

Comment: I am only aware of how to render a HTML page through pasting the path. I would be grateful if someone could explain how to directly open the file instead.

Comment: Either right click the name of your file on the left pane in vs code and simply select _copy path_, paste in your browser's address bar it will work fine or just paste **file:///Users/robertg21/Visual%20Studio%20Code%20Projects/hello_html/index.html**.

Comment: What exactly is the path you are pasting? What does that mean?

Comment: The code is exactly the same as in my file. The name of the file is index.html

Comment: CTRL+O works on some browsers to open the file.

Comment: What browser? Because in Firefox for me at least, local files need to be prefixed with `file://` to open.

Comment: Are you sure you saved the file? Also, if you try a simpler editor such as Notepad++ there is the option to open the file in your browser from the `Run` menu.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the suggestions. I realized that I needed to save the file for it to run. Sorry for causing inconvenience.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of user error

Comment: You can delete your question. Glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your file and open it by your browser, and you can open it directly.
I have added the screenshot below.[image]

Comment: Please do not take solutions from the comments and post as your own answer.